# Empty segments for Codeigniter URI custom Routing

Tags: php, codeigniter

Probably, this sort of questions are asked before but those doesn't address my problem. Anyway, I'm using this routing settings in my `applications/config/routes.php` file

```
$route['most-popular-movies-(:num)'] = 'movies/search/popular/$1';
```

where

1. Controller = movies
2. Function = search
3. Segment1 = popular
4. Segment2 = (Page #)

Now, I want to get the two segments in my controller but it seams routing overwrites the segments and I'm just getting one segment i.e: `most-popular-movies-1` when using `$this->uri->segment_array()`

Any Standard Solution?

**EDIT:**

I can use this method to split the URI inside my controller

```
explode('-', $this->uri->segment(1));
```

but this doesn't look to be a standard.

Comment: which is another segment that u want?

Comment: Two segments that come after "function" t.e: `popular` and `$1`

Comment: `$this->uri->rsegment_array()` to get the segments from URI

Comment: also try using * `$route['most-popular-movies-(.*)'] = 'movies/search/popular/$1';`

Answer (score 0):

Like this. use `uri_string()`.

```
$uri = $this->uri->uri_string();//most-popular-movies-1
$segments = explode('-',$uri);
//print_r($segments);.//array of segments
echo $segments[1];//output popular
```

Comment: I updated my question 2 min ago please check. Thank you!

Comment: see the answer for you.